# Redirecting to original page after successful login returns raw data instead of URL name

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building an application using Spring boot with Spring security and front end reactJS. My code works well with authentication. But now i am planning to redirect the user to his previous requested page in case he has to login again.

I can extract targetUrl i.e. previous page from the successhandler but when i do a console.log(data) at the UI. I get the raw html data instead of URL name. I dont know why and how to open such a raw html code or can i send just html URL name from successhandler instead it sends complete raw html code? Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Expected console.log(data) - https://localhost:8080/addpage.html

Actual console.log(data) - raw html data of addpage.html

ApplicationSecurity.java

```
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
@Autowired
private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/CSS/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/JS/*").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/*").authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(5).and().invalidSessionUrl("/login.html");
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html");

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

}
}
```

RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
 public class RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends 
 SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler   {

  private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    System.out.println(savedRequest);

     if (savedRequest == null) {
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         if (session != null) {
             String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("url_prior_login");
             if (redirectUrl != null) {
                 session.removeAttribute("url_prior_login");
                 getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
             } else {
                 super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
             }
         } else {
             super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
         }

         return;
     }

     String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
     System.out.println(targetUrlParameter);
     if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
             || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
         requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
         super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

         return;
     }

     clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);

     // Use the DefaultSavedRequest URL
     String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
     System.out.println(targetUrl);
     logger.debug("Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: " + targetUrl);
     getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);


     }


 }
```

UI code :

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/login",
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }.bind(this),
                error:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data.responseJSON.message);
                }
            });
```

console.log(data) - returns raw html code of targetURL which i cannot open as a html file. I need the html file name returned by targetURL from successhandler so that i can use window.location.href to open the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the `redirect url` to response.

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
 // ... get target url
 String targetUrl = "";
 try {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.OK);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write(targetUrl);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a mime type issue.  Inspect your web traffic with chrome inspect and make sure your headers are set correctly:

Response headers:

Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

Request headers:

Accept:text/html

etc.