# defaultSuccessUrl not correctly rendering the html page

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to setup a defaultSuccessUrl using Spring security and AngularJS, but after a success login the html page is loaded in the network but not displayed.
here is my security config

```
   http
      .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/")
          .successHandler(this.authSuccess)
          .failureHandler(this.authFailure).permitAll()
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/components/hello.jsp", true);


    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .logout()
             .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccess)
             .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
             .invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll();
```

but when I chec the network I can see that post request for the login was redirected with 302 status code and Hello.jsp was loaded with 200 Status [image]

however I still have the login page displayed and not the hello.jsp page.
Angular service for login :

```
this_.login = function(data) {
    return $http.post(_contextPath + '/',
            "username=" + data.username + "&password=" + data.password, {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }).success(function(response) {
        return response.status;
    }).error(function(response) {
        return response.status;
    })
};
```

Any one knows why?

Comment: How do you post the login form ? Ajax ?

Comment: @chaoluo I'm using AngularJS at the front end. I just updated my first comment with the service for the post request

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ajax` to post the login form, so the page can't redirect to the success url, you can return the default url and then redirect to the url at the front end. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924104/redirecting-to-original-page-after-successful-login-returns-raw-data-instead-of/43928463#43928463)